# IconButton from MUI no longer changes hover color with makeStyles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi I was looking in a way to change the hover color from IconButton However the [solution-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/iconbutton-hover-focus-cnexr?fontsize=14&file=/demo.js) that I found doesn't seem to be working anymore

This is what I have [Code-Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-snowflake-9ygxt?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `!important` to your style then it should work

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  customHoverFocus: {
    "&:hover, &.MuiIconButton": { background: "yellow !important" }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Yeah, that indeed worked. Is that like a new change or something ? cause it used to work before without it

Comment: Imports in the solution you found and in your question are different probably they have difference in core.

Comment: I'm sure is different version cause I'm using the latest and that answer was a bit older.

Answer (score 1):

From https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#style-library:

> The style library used by default in v5 is emotion. While migrating from JSS to emotion, and if you are using JSS style overrides for your components (for example overrides created by makeStyles), you will need to take care of the CSS injection order. To do so, you need to have the StyledEngineProvider with the injectFirst option at the **top of your component tree**.

If I change your index.js to the following, the style overrides work:

```
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <App />
  </StyledEngineProvider>,
  rootElement
);
```

[image: Edit Using JSS in v5]

In addition to adding `<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>`, I also removed `StrictMode` since `makeStyles` doesn't support it -- styles generated by `makeStyles` will not get maintained in the DOM reliably in strict mode.

Since you're using v5, the better option would be to avoid `makeStyles` (which is deprecated in v5) entirely and use `styled` instead. Then you don't need the index.js changes and can keep strict mode.

```
import React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";

const StyledIconButton = styled(IconButton)(`
  &:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`);
```

[image: Edit override IconButton styles]

Comment: Oh interesting, this seems to be the "proper" way to do it. Question is it wrong then to just simplify it and add !important in the style to override ? What would be the difference between this vs !important ?

Comment: @ReactPotato The "proper" way to do it is to avoid `makeStyles` entirely. I've added an example using `styled`.

Comment: Yeah I saw it, I'm gonna use that instead. But wanted to know like what harm is to use one vs the other if that makes sense.

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea (and unnecessary) to use `!important`. Once you add `!important`, those styles can only be overridden by styles that also use `!important`. When overrides don't work without `!important`, it is generally due to insufficient [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). When the specificity of styles is otherwise the same, the order in which their declarations appear determines which styles win -- thus using `injectFirst` for the Emotion styles causes the JSS styles from `makeStyles` to come after and win.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the answer!